# Heroku Error H14 - No web processes running

Tags: heroku-cli

Please Help

I'm receiving the error code above in my app. I'm receiving the above error code in my Heroku App.

Not sure what the cause is or how to fix it.

Below is an extract of the error log printout:

2023-03-27T16:22:04.931992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=6f0a5f71-2072-4f30-8dc7-6e88c899c20b fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:22:05.265465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=55011ac6-660c-4498-9fcd-2ed1fc0edb59 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:27:23.864813+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=9de245a0-7095-456e-877e-c37e043186b8 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:27:24.241859+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=32b15b7d-b98e-4595-a5a7-4f34c897bb3a fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:35:01.520955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=54af9459-51f1-43c4-9bbc-9fd27e9a9572 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:35:02.016574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=fd83960b-e8ee-4e64-b3bf-1795ec30ca19 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:41:14.995107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=cb16a0a7-a8c9-472f-9c0a-223c017a7e41 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:41:15.356795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=ec12174f-008d-49be-9cf2-599acb9141d0 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:51:13.799438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=5078ec97-c8be-4ac3-a4c0-fae88efb2a05 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-03-27T16:51:14.145088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=jamies-nightscout.herokuapp.com request_id=fb6bbb55-0a11-4fac-838c-2c718413b063 fwd="197.91.184.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Canot operate the app - don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Procfile" file.  Do you have one in your root directory?  contents file should be:
web: gunicorn .wsgi
Should be written in a code editor.
File name has no extension.
[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration][1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).